# SQL: How to compare datetime with whitespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a column`date` and it is type of `datetime` with format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.000`

my problem is for some dates there is a single space and others there are two spaces between the date and the time

eg.

```
2009-08-20 13:44:12.753
2009-08-20  13:44:12.753
```

even though the times are the same when i try compare them they do not match due to the whitespace. i have tried using the `replace(date, ' ', '')` function but this does not keep the datetime format correctly `Aug2020091:44PM`

how would i compare these dates to ignore the whitespace but not affect the datetime itself?

Comment: Did you try `replace(date, '  ', ' ')`?

Comment: How are you getting the string representation of your dates?  If the column is of type datetime, then this is not how they are stored, but how you are outputting them.

Comment: @Kaf: i am using sql server

Comment: I agree with @Paddy. Is data type of the column a string type?

Comment: no it is of type datetime

Comment: @HipHipArray if it is a datetime , then you should have any problem. the only problem is when you're dealing with strings....

Comment: I am not sure why you having comparing issues if they are already datetime. Try to `CONVERT` or `CAST` them again to `DATETIME` before comparing.

Comment: `DATETIME` columns in SQL Server **have no format** - they're stored as 8-byte binary values. The format only comes into play when displaying those values as string, e.g. in SSMS or your app. Therefore, comparing two `DATETIME` values never has any issues with whitespace - it's just comparing two (binary) `DATETIME` values

Comment: To add on what @marc_s pointed. Even if they had an internal format, we should not care. SQL-Server takes care so that comparisons work correctly.

Comment: Problems may occur when you are comparing datetimes stored in `DATETIME` columns with datetimes coming from your applications/users and those have various formats.

Answer (score 3):

why would'nt you use

```
replace(date, '  ', ' ')
```

I mean  - replace just 2  white spaces into one

( it is not clear from my code but here it on pseudo )

```
 replace(date, '[ ][ ]', '[ ]')  //where [ ] is whitespace.
```

solution #2:

use this :

```
SELECT CAST('2009-08-20 13:44:12.753' AS DATETIME) --nevermind the spaces
SELECT CAST('2009-08-20       13:44:12.753' AS DATETIME)  --nevermind the spaces
```